# How do I populate a number of labels?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to programming and not really sure what I am doing.  I am trying to replicate a calendar in a WindowsForm in c#. I started with a TableLayoutPanel(6x7).  I added a regular Panel in each of the cells of the table layout panel.  Within the regular panel, I have a label and a listbox.  I want int day to be in the label.  I don't want to hardcode it.  And I want the labels to change appropriately when I move to the next month.  How can I accomplish this?

Here is a picture of the layout:

[image: Example]

So I am doing this in a group and the following is what one of my groupmates came up with.  It populates the labels nicely with the exception of December 2013 and June 2014.  Any idea what might cause this?  Is this an ok way of doing things?

```
` private void dtpMonthTab_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.setCal();
    }

    private void setCal()
    {


        DateTime now = dtpMonthTab.Value;
        int month = now.Month;
        int year = now.Year;
        DateTime startmonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);


        DayOfWeek dow = startmonth.DayOfWeek;
        int daynumber = (int)dow;
        //MessageBox.Show(" testing: " + dow + daynumber);

        switch (daynumber)
        {
            case 0:
                //MessageBox.Show("The number is zero!");
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(-6);
                label1.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label2.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label3.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label4.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label5.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label6.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label7.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                break;
            case 1:
                //MessageBox.Show("The number is one!");
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(-1);
                label1.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label2.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label3.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label4.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label5.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label6.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label7.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                break;
            case 2:
                //MessageBox.Show("The number is 2!");
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(-2);
                label1.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label2.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label3.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label4.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label5.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label6.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label7.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                break;
            case 3:
                //MessageBox.Show("The number is 3!");
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(-3);
                label1.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label2.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label3.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label4.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label5.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label6.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label7.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                break;
            case 4:
                //MessageBox.Show("The number is 4!");
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(-4);
                label1.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label2.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label3.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label4.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label5.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label6.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label7.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                break;
            case 5:
                //MessageBox.Show("The number is 5!");
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(-5);
                label1.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label2.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label3.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label4.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label5.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label6.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label7.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                break;
            case 6:
                //MessageBox.Show("The number is 6!");
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(-6);
                label1.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label2.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label3.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label4.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label5.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label6.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                label7.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
                startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("I'm sorry, I don't understand that!");
                break;

        }

        label8.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label9.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label10.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label11.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label12.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label13.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label14.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label15.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label16.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label17.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label18.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label19.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label20.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label21.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label22.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label23.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label24.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label25.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label26.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label27.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label28.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label29.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label30.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label31.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label32.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label33.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label34.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label35.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label36.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label37.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label38.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label39.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label40.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label41.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);

        label42.Text = String.Format("{0:dd}", startmonth);
        startmonth = startmonth.AddDays(1);
    } `
```

Comment: You should create the labels programatically and add them to the parent control. In a loop you'd simply determine the position and add them to an appropriate data structure (e.g., array) for convenient use.

Comment: How would I do that?  Is the parent control the tablelayout panel, or the regular panel?

Comment: You don't need to use a table layout at all, if there are no other layout requirements. You simply use two *for* loops with *x* and *y*, where both together represent a coordinate in your parent panel. Additionally, you set *label.Top* and *label.Left* based on *x* and *y*.

Comment: Please include the image in the question.  `photobucket.com` is block at my workplace.

Comment: I recommend using a usercontrol for the day-objects...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TableLayoutPanel.GetControlFromPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getcontrolfromposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Once you have the control cast it to what you know is there (you said "regular Panel") and use it accordingly. The problem now is that those Panel items do not expose their label+listbox contents, but [Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property is exposing them in a way. I would suspect that `Controls[0]` would always give the label, and `Controls[1]` would give you the listbox, but not sure. You would have to cast them. It depends on the order they were created in each cell.

You should make your own user control, like in the comment from Mr47. Your user control would be a panel with label and listbox in it, and then you would have to replace all panels in all cells with this new user control. You should then create additional properties (Label and ListBox) that would expose the label and the listbox. This way programming would be easier, and the code would be more resistant to bugs.

Also, note that five rows are not enough for a month, if for instance first day of the month falls on Saturday.

Comment: FYI Each container control has it's own Controls collection. In a setup step you could store references to the controls in a (or two, one for text, one for the list) collection indexed by date or day of month... Then when you update the controls use the collection references.

Comment: @rheitzman if we let Visual Studio's editor to make the code then the editor will set the Controls property for each control. If OP goes to create and place the controls in his own code then my answer is of very little use.

Comment: I meant to add this comment to the OP - sorry. To OPer can add the controls in code and give them names that related to the dates to be displayed, then index to them via name: <container>.Controls("Oct_22_2013")